# Некоторые файлы не передаются при push локального репозитория

Tags: git, github

Возникла проблема при push'e на github локального репозитория: некоторые файлы не передаются, которые были изменены, но только в названии имени, т.е. раньше было text - теперь Text, на сервере остаются файлы такими же, как собственно исправить это?

Win7, tortoisegit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В ОС Windows нет разницы между названиями **text** и **Text**

Переименовывайте файл средствами git

```
git mv text.txt Text.txt –f
```

Comment: так мне для всего проекта нужно это делать . Сайт на Kohana 3.3 там требуеться чтобы все имена контроллеров начинались с верхнего регистра. Нельзя ли в самой tortoise настроить это?

Comment: Это не задача tortoise. Это Ваша задача.

Comment: > требуеться чтобы все имена контроллеров начинались с верхнего регистра

Ну напишите скрипт на любом языке, который рекурсивно переименует все файлы средствами git.